# Firefox not applying computed styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I am using FF version 52.0. I have changes made to a style sheet and Firefox is not applying them. I can see that Firefox is grabbing the style sheet with updates AND when inspecting can see that under computer styles that it is registering my changes. However when I inspect the Rules, those computed rules are not present on the element I'm attempting to alter.

I have tested this in FF Private windows, off my machine, cleared caches in Advanced, all with the same result. Adding -moz- prefix for transform also appears to make no difference. Ideas anyone?

- Firefox, there are other computed classes that are not applied
- Firefox, computed classes not applied
- Chrome, computed styles applied

[Firefox Does Not Apply Some Computed Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubAIN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add ?v=1.0 to the end of your stylesheet include as in:

```
<link href="/css/style.css?v=1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This will version your CSS, and make completely sure there is not caching issues, which I think there is. If this works for you I can also show you how to auto version your CSS.